# What are examples of a 10 digit safe prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

I am stuck with a question with regards to finding an example of 10 digit safe prime number. I need the number for cryptography purposes. (for Diffie-Hellman key exchange)

I know that a safe prime is derived as such: 
safe prime = (p x 2) + 1

where safe prime is a prime number , and p is a prime number as well.

I have googled for quite awhile and haven't found any solution yet. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If the question is "what is the smallest safe prime which can be stored as a signed 32-bit integer (*e.g. as with the Integer class in Java*)" then the answer is $5$.  Surely, you mean to ask instead what the *largest* safe prime is that can be stored as a signed 32-bit integer, a much more interesting question instead, or what the smallest safe prime that can *not* be stored as a signed 32-bit integer (*or equivalent questions for unsigned integers*).

Comment: Hi, so sorry, i've edited my question. I meant to find a 10 digit safe prime number!

Comment: $1000000007$ is the smallest 10-digit prime number, and happens to be safe. – Just search on any (sufficiently large) public list of prime numbers.

Comment: By definition a 10 digit prime is not "safe" of course. DH with that prime is quite easily breakable.

Answer (score 3):

According to MathStudio's prime checker, $\ p=1,000,000,007\ $ is the smallest 10-digit prime, and $\ \frac{p-1}{2}=500,000,003\ $ is also prime, which would make $\ p\ $ the smallest 10-digit safe prime number.

Comment: For $p$ to be safe, $p+1$ **also** should have one large prime factor (so be of the form $2*q$ for $q$ some other prime, preferably). This $p+1$ has lots of small factors (even in powers) so is cryptographically not a good prime, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime) e.g.

Comment: for Diffie-Helman you need strong primes. Safe primes are not good enough.

Comment: "Safe prime" appears to be a term of art (see https://books.google.com.au/books?id=rUApHgaTVx0C&pg=PA411) whose definition is precisely as given by the OP—that is, a prime $\ p\ $ for which $\ \frac{p-1}{2}\ $ is also prime.  I have to admit I wasn't aware of that when I wrote my answer. Since $10$-digit primes are cryptographically useless anyway (as you point out in your comment above), I had simply assumed that if the term was not merely a coinage by the OP, then it had been defined correctly.

Comment: this was the older notion until newer attacks on DH groups were found that made the new $p+1$ condition necessary as well. Safe is a time dependent notion in a way, we’d better call them “primes that are safe from all generic attacks” ( as known in 2019).

Answer (score 2):

For $10$ digits about one number in $\log(3\cdot 10^9) \approx 22$ is prime.  If you limit yourself to numbers of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$ about one in $8$ is prime because you have avoided factors of $2$ and $3$, so just start trying them.  Note that if your first prime is of the form $6k+1$, doubling it and adding one makes a multiple of $3$, so your first prime should be of the form $6k+5$.  The second will be of this form as well.  It should only take about $64$ tries, on average, to find one.

Answer (score 1):

For $10$ digits about one number in $\log(3\cdot 10^9) \approx 22$ is prime.  If you limit yourself to numbers of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$ about one in $8$ is prime, so just start trying them.  Note that if your first prime is of the form $6k+1$, doubling it and adding one makes a multiple of $3$, so your first prime should be of the form $6k+5$.  The second will be of this form as well.  It should only take about $64$ tries, on average, to find one.